# Arduino String does not properly convert integer to string

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, tinkercad

I am using TinkerCad as Arduino UNO R3 simulator. My aim is to convert int to string but the following code prints 188 instead of 180.

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
}


void loop()
{
  Serial.println(String(180));
}
```

[image: Serial monitor output]

Output is `188` as you can see in the screenshot from TinkerCad serial monitor above. Why is there a weird problem with `String`?

Comment: Reduce baud speed.  Test using examples from the String() constructor page.  It is difficult to believe that you've found a bug in this class.

Comment: I have tried with ```Serial.begin(9600)```too. It does not make any difference.

Comment: It's not the question, but using String is never a good idea. To print an `int` use `print`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a tinkercad problem. Your weird sketch works well on a real Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with tinkercad.
`String (intval) or (String) intval was not working.`

Kludge: using `lcd.write(int);` instead if possible (i.e. use int where you can and send int directly to write).

Answer (score 0):

That's really weird. Try this:

```
int intValue = 180;
string stringValue;

void setup()
  {
    Serial.begin(9600);
  }


void loop()
  {
    stringValue = String(intValue);
    Serial.println(stringValue);
  
}
```